# Jquery how to read which li element is clicked

Tags: jquery

Hello i am trying to make my custom made combobox with using jquery and ul li menus. So when mouse clicked to the li element i have to read its value and set its parent to the clicked element value etc. Basic selecting method.

So how can i read the clicked li element value and set that value to the parent of it. Here my structure.

```
  <ul class="topnav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">All Abilities</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Fire Master</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Great Attack</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manyak Ability</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Super Ability</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deneme Ability</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Here the jquery code

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled - Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav

        $("ul.topnav li").click(function () { //When trigger is clicked...

            //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
            $(this).find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

            $(this).hover(function () {
            }, function () {
                $(this).find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
            });

            //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function () {    //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
        });


        $("ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a").click(function () { //When trigger is clicked...

            //****************** none of these working*************************//
            var srVal1 = $(this).find("ul.subnav").val();
            var srVal2 = $(this).find("subnav").val();
            var srVal3 = $(this).find("li a").val();
            var srVal4 = $(this).find("a").val();
            var srVal5 = $(this).parent("li").val();
            var srVal5 = $(this).find("li").val();
            var srVal6 = $(this).val();
            var srVal7 = $(this).parent("li a").val();

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a').click(function(){

    $(this).parents('ul.subnav').siblings('a').html($(this).text());

});
```

Comment: Hmm, weird cause it worked on my implementation using your own markup. This does the replacing part by the way.

`$(this)` in this context would refer to the `a` clicked. All this does is select the `ul.subnav` that holds it, then select the nearest `a` ('All Abilities') and then replace its content with `$(this).text()`. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: i found the problem. if i make the script like this it works :   $("ul.topnav li ul.subnav li").click(function () { //When trigger i

Answer (score 2):

You want `$(this).text()`, `.val()` is for form elements.

Here's a jsfiddle for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/JbRqM/1/

Notice I used `.parents('li')` to select the parent `<li>` tag of the nested ul:

```
$(this).parents('li').html($(this).text());
```

Comment: how exactly use ? i tried but not working     var srVal9 = $(this).text;

Comment: I just edited my answer, you can view a working example at the jsfiddle link and the important line is: `$(this).parents('li').html($(this).text());
`

Comment: not working edited version too check link : http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/1572/notworkingd.png

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this).parents("li")` instead of `$(this).parent("li")`

`.parent("li")` only looks in the immediate parent to the element, which is `<ul>`

`.parents("li")` looks through all of the parent collections. More specifically, use `.parents("li:first")`

Comment: how exactly use. i tried this way but not worked        var srVal11 = $(this).parents("li").val();

Comment: Oh, you just want the clicked one? try `alert($(this).text());`

Comment: not working unfortunately :( here the image : http://img807.imageshack.us/img807/1813/notworking2.png